# Line Graph with Bar Graph in Excel 2010

Tags: graph, excel, excel-2003, vba

I have a requirement to create a Bar graph for the results of the current time period and along with that a line graph which displays the previous time period, this is using a Excel 2010 Workbook.

[image: Bar Graph with a Line Graph]

Is the above graph type possible in Excel 2003 or Excel 2010 Work Books? If so, how do I do the same?

I read somewhere that a XY Cluster graph would do the trick, but have not been able to reproduce the same effect.

Comment: Create a bar chart with the three series, then change the type of the third series to "line" (right-click on the series on the chart and choose "change series chart type").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly tidied-up recorded macro:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet1'!$B$7:$E$14")
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .SeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlLine
End With
```

Source data for my example:

```
Month     Series1  Series2  Series3
J       10       15       5
F       20       30       10
M       30       45       15
A       40       60       45
M       50       75       72
Jun     60       90       24
Jul     70       105      35
```

Comment: The above macro will work when an existing chart already exists also? Currently I am able to create a new chart, but will need to make more modifications to get the correct X and Y axis and the labels correctly displayed.

Comment: Thanks that helps :-) ... I was trying with only 2 columns of numbers and getting a Invalid Value error...

Comment: If I do not have a continuous set of columns, would the above still work?

    Month     Series1  SeriesX  Series2  SeriesY Series3
    J           10       15       5         15       5
    F           20       30       10        30       10
    M           30       45       15        45       15
    A           40       60       45        60       45
    M           50       75       72        75       72
    Jun         60       90       24        90       24


.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$7, 'Sheet1'!$C$1:$C$7,'Sheet1'!$E$1:$E$7,'Sheet1'!$G$1:$G$7")

Comment: I got it to work, using:

        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("QARUN_Templates").Range("A29:A39")
        
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        
        .SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Sheets("QARun_Templates").Range("D29:D39")
        .SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Sheets("QARun_Templates").Range("I29:I39")
        .SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Sheets("QARun_Templates").Range("D129:D139")

But my labels are still coming wrong, will work more on it and post the same... thanks :-)